# Convert Pandas Dataframe Strings to Decimal (Inc. Empty Strings)

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I have written a utility function that will convert strings to decimals- it also returns a zero decimal if the string is empty.

```
from decimal import * 

def convert_string_to_decimal(some_string):
    return Decimal('0.00') if (some_string == '' or some_string.isspace()) else Decimal(some_string)
```

I have a pandas dataframe of a bank statement with two columns that I would now like to convert to decimals. They are called `debit` and `credit`. How best should I go about using the function above? Secondly, is this even recommended? I read somewhere that one should use `Decimal` for currency.

Comment: This is true that `Decimal` better handle computations to avoid floating point errors, however this is not ideal for `pandas` as it won't vectorize. What you could do is to work with integers using cents (or less if needed).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for new function, you can do it with astype...

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'debit': ['1.11','', '2.22', '3.33', ' '], 'credit': ['1.2345', '2.3456', '3.00', '4', '5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
  id debit credit
0  A  1.11      1
1  B            2
2  C  2.22      3
3  D  3.33      4
4  E            5
'''
df['debit'] = df['debit'].replace(' ', '').replace('', '0.00').astype(float)
df['credit'] = df['credit'].replace(' ', '').replace('', '0.00').astype(float)
print(df)
'''
  id  debit  credit
0  A   1.11  1.2345
1  B   0.00  2.3456
2  C   2.22  3.0000
3  D   3.33  4.0000
4  E   0.00  5.0000
'''
```

Comment: I see, thanks @d r - but what if I wanted to change it to a `Decimal`?

Comment: You can do it later when the data are extracted out of df to be presented in any way you want. While inside it doesn't make sense. There are some strict rules with  df dtypes.

Comment: Btw, the first print of df has wrong values in column credit. My mistake, but you got the picture and that counts. Sorry...